# How do I stop my Tumblr's header from repeating on every page (even though I have infinite scrolling)?

Tags: html, header, tumblr

here is my tumblr page so you can see what i mean:

http://alinabrown23.tumblr.com/

as you can see, the entire header and creator link begins at the start of each "new page" as you continue to scroll down. what can i change in my html code or settings to stop this from happening? i love this theme but everything has its glitches.

please help me if you can, it would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your theme, you have this line of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://proto.jp/js/tumblrAutoPager.js"></script>
```

After it, try adding this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tumblrAutoPager.ppId = 'postWrapper';
</script>
```

Comment: @Alina: It looks like it's in your blog's description.